# Linux FTP put success output

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ftp

I have a bash script that creates backups incrementally(daily) and full(on Mondays). Every 7 days the script combines the week of backups(full and Incremental) and sends them off to an FTP server, the problem i am having is i want to delete the files from my backup directory after the FTP upload is finished, but i cant do that until i know the file was successfully uploaded. I need to figure out how to capture the '226 transfer complete' so i can use that in an 'IF' statement to delete the backup files. Any help is greatly appreciated. also he is my FTP portion of the script

```
if [ -a "$WKBKDIR/weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz" ]; then 

    HOST=192.168.40.30       #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
    USER=username            #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
    PASS=password            #This is the password for the FTP user.


    ftp -inv $HOST << EOF
    user $USER $PASS
    cd /baks
    lcd $WKBKDIR
    put weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz
    bye 
    EOF

fi
```

I could use whatever mean i needed i suppose, FTP was something already setup for another backup function for something else, thanks

2nd EDIT Ahmed the rsync works great in test from command line, its a lot faster than FTP, the server is on the local network so SSH not that big of a deal but nice to have for added security, i will finish implementing in my script tomorrow, thanks again

Comment: are you limited to FTP service? Can you get or do you have access to scp on remote server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### FTP OPTION

The simple solution would be to do something like this:

```
ftp -inv $HOST >ftp-results-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.out 2>&1 <<-EOF


    user $USER $PASS
    cd /baks
    bin
    lcd $WKBKDIR
    put weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz
    bye 
EOF
```

Also there is an issue with your *here-document* syntax; there is no space between `<<` and the delimiter word (in your case EOF) and I added a `-` because you are putting white-spaces before the ACTUAL delimeter (it's tabbed in for the if / fi block) so the [-] is required

Now when you do this; you can parse the output file to look for the successful put of the file. For example:

```
  if grep -q '226 transfer complete' ftp-results-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.out; then 
         echo "It seems that FTP transfer completed fine, we can schedule a delete"
         echo "rm -f $PWD/weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz" >> scheduled_cleanup.sh
  fi
```

and  just run scheduled_cleanup.sh using `cron` at a given time; this way you will have some margin before the files are cleaned up

If your remote FTP server has good SITE or PROXY options you may be able to get the remote FTP to run a checksum on the uploaded file after successful upload and return the result.

### SCP / RSYNC OPTION

Using FTP is clunky and dangerous, you should really try and see if you can have scp or ssh access to the remote system.

If you can then generate an ssh key if you don't have one using ssh-keygen:
        `ssh-keygen -N "" -t rsa -f ftp-rsa`

put the ftp-rsa.pub file into the $HOST/home/$USER/.ssh/authorized_keys and you have a much nicer method for uploading files:

```
if scp -B -C weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz $USER@$HOST:/baks/ ; then
   echo Upload successful 1>&2
else
   echo Upload failed 1>&2
fi
```

Or better yet using rsync:

```
if rsync --progress -a weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz $HOST:/baks/ ; then
   echo Upload successful 1>&2
else
   echo Upload failed 1>&2
fi
```

et voilà you are done since rsync works over ssh you are happy and secure

Answer (score 1):

Try the next

```
#!/bin/bash

runifok() { echo "will run this when the transfer is OK"; }

if [ -a "$WKBKDIR/weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz" ]; then 

  HOST=192.168.40.30       #This is the FTP servers host or IP address.
  USER=username            #This is the FTP user that has access to the server.
  PASS=password            #This is the password for the FTP user.

  ftp -inv <<EOF | grep -q '226 transfer complete' && runifok
user $USER $PASS
cd /baks
lcd $WKBKDIR
put weekending-$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY.tar.gz
bye 
EOF

fi
```

test it and when will run ok - replace the echo in the `runifok` function for your commands what want execute after the upload is succesful.

Comment: How can print message if there was an error in transmission?